# Reflective LCD PC monitor?

Tags: monitors, displays, e-ink

It is generally advised not to watch screens before going to bed, as it interferes with the natural melatonin cycle.

Therefore, I was hoping to find an e-ink monitor for my PC, just for text editing and email. However, e-ink displays are slow to refresh, so scrolling through text/webpages is frustrating.

So I was thinking if there is a reflective LCD monitor for my PC, that reflects light rather than transmitting it. I know the technology of reflective LCD exists, but is there actually a consumer-grade PC monitor with this? I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is too little demand for a PC-sized reflective LCD screen for companies to make them. They're normally found on small things like clocks and calculators. You might be able to order an LCD panel without a backlight though! Or maybe you could disconnect the power for the backlight on an LCD panel and see if the ambient light is enough to still use it.

Comment: A lot of devices are now coming with a "night mode" which reduces the blue light so that it doesn't disrupt your sleep cycle as much. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Lawrence, For some people, or on some monitors, even that software is not effective. The characteristics of the monitor itself (backlight bleed, minimum brightness, color temperature, etc.) are not something that software can change.

Comment: @Romen fair enough